# WIX Bootstrapper Extract then Install 3rd Party Software

Tags: wix, installation, extract, archive, bootstrapper

I'm working on creating a bootstrapper project in WIX. One of the 3rd party installers that must run before mine is a little strange. It's actually a self-extracting archive that saves the real installer to disk, then runs it automatically once the extraction is finished.

Unfortunately, as soon as the self-extracting exe has finished extracting, WIX thinks that installation is complete and goes on to the next step, while the installer is actually just starting to run.

Is there a way to properly detect and wait for that installation to finish?

Thanks for your help,

-Gary

Comment: Why don't you skip the self-extracting part and use "real installer" directly in your bootstrapper. This can't end up well the way you're doing it right now ;p

Comment: I had been hoping to avoid doing that; the real installer includes hundreds of support files that I'd have to reference. It is my backup plan though, if there's no good way to do what I described above.

Comment: Normally self-extracting installers like this have a command line option to wait for the child process to finish before exiting.